# How Can I Export Data With App Engine and JAVA?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, import, export

I'm trying to export data from my project to Excel or CSV.

I'm using App Engine with JAVA.

I read in this link that I can do it with Python, so I installed Python's SDK. (http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Using-the-new-bulkloader)

I'm doing the following:

1- Run CMD

2- Go to Python folder

3- Write "python" (So I'm using python now)

4- Write "import os"

5- Write "os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine")   (to go to appengine folder)

6- Run Bulkloader: "$ ./bulkloader.py --create_config --url http://MYAPP.appspot.com/remote_api --filename generated_bulkloader.yaml"

and cmd tell me "Invalid Sintax"

What I'm doing wrong??

Do anybody can import and export data in App Engine with JAVA?

Thanks

Comment: yes i made it but with my own function. i just load list of data i want to export and then make it excel with jxl (Java Excel)

Answer (score 0):

There are no tools as such provided to do a data export. The best option for you would be:

- Identify the data that you need.
- Since you want to use Java, write your own Servlet with required parameters that can extract the data,  generate the data identified in (1) and allow you to download the
  file.
- Pay attention to securing the Servlet in (2), so that only
  authorized users can invoke it.
- Another alternative could be to write
  your own Cron Task and FTP out the file to another Server.